# Does deferred.done() fire before ajaxComplete()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request chained with a `.done` method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $formAction,
    data: $form.serialize(),
})
.done(function () {
    refreshComplaintCategoryResults($categoryId);
});
```

There is also an `.ajaxComplete()` used to re-initialise some events:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqXhr, ajaxOptions) {
    reinitAll();
});
```

Which one should fire first? The `.done()` method or the `ajaxComplete()` method?

I want to be able to do the `refreshComplaintCategoryResults()` after the  `reinitAll()` method. I do not want to call the `reinitAll()` method again, as it will get called twice (I cannot remove it from the `ajaxComplete()`) method, but I cannot put the `refreshComplaintCategoryResults()` in the `ajaxComplete()` method.

**UPDATE:**

I have added this to the ajaxComplete() method to get what I want to achieve and removed the .done() method. However, it seems a little messy to be checking the url in order to complete an action:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqXhr, ajaxOptions) {
    reinitAll();

    if (ajaxOptions.url === "ComplaintWorkflow/GetComplaintCategoryResults")
    {
        $("tr[data-action-url]")[0].click();
    }
});
```

Is there not a better way?

Comment: Looks like you have all the makings of a test right there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: why don't you try it and find out? add both handlers to your `$.ajax` call

Comment: can always use the data available to you in the arguments to your advantage and conditionally call `reinitAll()`

Comment: why has someone down voted? I didn't think the question was that bad.

Comment: Why aren't you using event delegation for your events? The use of `ajaxComplete` here seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does `deferred.done()` fire before `ajaxComplete()`?

Yes, it does. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/937m8yd0/):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqXhr, ajaxOptions) {
    console.log("ajaxComplete");
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: "{'a':1}",
})
.done(function () {
    console.log("ajax.done");
});
```

Console output:

```
ajax.done
ajaxComplete
```

Comment: Thanks @canon - I found the answer to doing the same. Thanks. I will have to use the ajaxOptions param in ajaxComplete to achieve what I want.